# Creating time limited AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am an instructor that teaches Bask/Command Line among other things. I have created a program for my final exam that provisions instances for each of my students to demonstrate what they have learned. I have created it so that using SQS and Lambda that I create the keypair and instance for the student whenever they want and that part is working fine, but I want to make it so that when I create the instance I also set something that will terminate it in 2 hours.

SQS doesn't allow a delay of that long. And I want the solution to be part of Amazon, if I put it in the instance (using the CLI or Bash) then the student might disrupt accidentally or on purpose).

Does anyone know an AWS feature or service that will allow you to schedule multiple individual events to occur at some point in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create "cron-like" task with [EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html)

I never used it myself but I would look in this direction if I wanted to setup a task 2 hours later that would terminate the instance.